# How to force files to close and open again when switching between git branches?

Tags: git, adobe-brackets

I have a frequent problem where I am working on the same files but in different branches, and if I forget to close my files before switching branches, the changes I made are carried over to my new branch, and then I have to use HEAD -- to reverse those changes... I'm wondering if there's a practical way to prevent this from happening... ie to force my text editor to close and open my files automatically when I switch branches. I'm using Brackets.

EDIT: So I've just now learned that another way to easily undo my changes (and maybe is better than the `HEAD --` version if I haven't staged anything) is to just use `git restore`, but this still doesn't prevent the issue in the first place.

Comment: Are your changes unsaved?

Comment: @Schwern they save on the fly.

Comment: I know [Atom](https://atom.io/) will update an unedited file when it changes on disk.

Comment: @Schwern I don't think I understand, if a file is unedited then how could it be updated?

Comment: If you have a file open in Atom without any unsaved changes, and the file changes on disk such as when one switches branches, Atom will show the updated file. Is this the behavior you're looking for? Or do you want saved but unstaged changes to be automatically undone when you switch branches? That seems like a dangerous feature.

Comment: You might consider not switching branches at all. If you want to view (or even modify) a copy of the version of a file of the same name that's in some other commit, use `git worktree add` to extract that commit to a different work-tree, which gives the file a different path name.